# ComponentQuery in ext 3.4

Tags: extjs3, component-query

Hi I am currently using ExtJS 4.2 and Siesta testing framework. In my test case I look up/traverse a component tree using Ext.ComponentQuery.query. I had to go back to ExtJS 3.4 and was wondering if there is an equivalent to Ext.ComponentQuery.query(other than DomQuery) that lets you search/traverse components.

Answer (score 0):

i think, "Ext.Element.query" would be helpful.
it uses css selector internally...

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same issue as you, the solution I found was using `Ext.Element.Select('selector')[0]`